# What are the differences between arc feature [branch-name] and git branch [branch-name]?

Tags: git, phabricator

What are the differences between `arc feature [branch-name]` and `git branch [branch-name]`?

They both seem to create a new branch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`arc feature [branch-name]` will:

- Create a branch based from the commit you currently have checked out,
- Set the tracking to the branch you have checked out (this will be to track the local branch, not the branch on your remote),
- Check out that branch.

`git branch [branch-name]` will only create a branch based from the commit you currently have checked out.

If you are using the Arcanist workflow, it is strongly recommended to use `arc feature` for your branches as this tends to lend itself well to the followup commands of `arc diff` and `arc land`.

Comment: Based on the description above, it should be equivalent to `git checkout -t -b [branch-name]`. So I'm not sure why it's necessary to "strongly recommend" using `arc feature`.

Comment: Perhaps because of developers who forget `-t`.

Comment: The current version of arcanist does not support `arc feature` any more. One use of `arc feature` for me was to list the state of each branch when entered without `[branch-name]`. Now that can be achieved using `arc branches`.